# How to add height for content post of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, height

I want to make my WordPress contents like blocks. I used CSS and PHP simple code for making 4 columns and it works. But I want the the content also have same and equal height.

[image]

I used a function to limit characters in contents but still the posts height are not equal.

```
function ld_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) { return 10; } add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'ld_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Actually I know that I can give them the height in css like

```
article {height:100px;}
```

but after doing this the contents will not be responsive anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to detect the highest content and set the height for all elements to the highest one.

In this case **#custom_element** is my container which contains all posts.

And **.content** is a container which contains my text, images, etc... for each single post.

**Short example:**

```
function resizeContent() {
    jQuery('#custom_element').each(function(){  

      // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
      var highestBox = 0;
      jQuery('.content').css("height","");

      // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
      jQuery('.content', this).each(function(){

        // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
        if(jQuery(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = jQuery(this).height(); 
        }

      });  

      // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest 
      jQuery('.content',this).height(highestBox);

    }); 
}
//adjust dimensions when loaded
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    resizeContent();
});
//adjust dimensions when window size gets changed
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeContent();
});
```

PHP-Example:

```
<div id="custom_element">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    .
    . 
    .
</div>
```